# Something wrong with cookie authentication in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: authentication, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc

How to use cookie authentication but not ASP.NET Core Identity?
It is my **controller**.It didn't work when I click submit.
Can someone give me advice?

```
public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(db_user _User)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {   
            if (_User.UserName != "123" && _User.UserPassword != "123")
            {
                ViewData["ErrorMessage"] = "error!!";
                return View();
            }

            
            var claims = new List<Claim>   
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, _User.UserName),
                
            };

            
            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                                       claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                //AllowRefresh = <bool>,
                // Refreshing the authentication session should be allowed.

                //ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10), 
                // The time at which the authentication ticket expires. A 
                // value set here overrides the ExpireTimeSpan option of 
                // CookieAuthenticationOptions set with AddCookie.

                //IsPersistent = true,
                // Whether the authentication session is persisted across 
                // multiple requests. When used with cookies, controls
                // whether the cookie's lifetime is absolute (matching the
                // lifetime of the authentication ticket) or session-based.

                //IssuedUtc = <DateTimeOffset>,
                // The time at which the authentication ticket was issued.

                //RedirectUri = <string>
                // The full path or absolute URI to be used as an http redirect response value.
            };

            // ***  Login *********
            HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                                                    new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
                                                    authProperties);
            #endregion

            return Content("<h3>Welcome</h3>");
        }

        // Something failed. Redisplay the form.
        return View();
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

         return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

It is my **model**

```
    namespace Cookie2.Model
{
    public class db_user
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string UserPassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It is my **.cshtml**

```
 @model Cookie2.Model.db_user
    


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "title";
    Layout = "_Layout";
}


    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Login" method="post">
        <label asp-for="UserName">
            <input asp-for="UserName">
        </label>
        <br />
        <label asp-for="UserPassword">
            <input asp-for="UserPassword">
        </label>
        <br>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

It is startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/AccessDeny";
                    options.LoginPath = "/Home/Login";
                }
            
            
            );
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

appreciation appreciation appreciation appreciation appreciation appreciation appreciation
appreciation appreciation appreciation appreciation appreciation appreciation appreciation

Comment: Hi @Haohao1198, what do you mean for `It didn't work`? Is the form data passwed to backend? Or any other problems? You may explain more detailed.

Comment: Hi @Rena, the webpage cannot be found . HTTP404

Comment: Hi @Haohao1198, where is the status code get, before hitting the HttpPost method or after HttpPost method running? Does it hit the HttpPost method but cannot return view successfully?

Comment: Hi @Haohao1198, I saw your `LoginPath` configure in Startup.cs is `Home/Login`, but in the login view, the form defines to `asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Login"`, and the tag helper generated url is `Login/Index`. But your backend action is `Login`. It should be `ControllerName/Login`. The url does not match each other. And this will cause 404 error.

Comment: @Rena .Yes,it can work now...Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the login view, the form defines to `asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Login"`, and the tag helper generated url is `Login/Index`.But your backend action is `Login`.It should be `ControllerName/Login`.The url does not match each other. And this will cause 404 error.